# Counting how many characters are in a string outputting syntax incorrect

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I'm trying to count how many characters are in a string using the following:

```
set "vnum=0.1.2"
for %%i in (%vnum%) do set count=%%~szi
if %count%==5(
    set "vtype=dev"
) else if %count%==3 (
    set "vtype=stable"
) else (
    set "vtype=unknown"
)
@echo "v%vnum%(%vtype%)"
@echo.
```

However when I run it, it's outputting `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

What am I doing wrong to where I cannot obtain the length of the string?

Comment: the `%~z` modifier works only with filenames, not with strings. There isn no  `%~s` modifier.

Comment: If you are expecting `%%~szi` to provide the number of characters in the string then you are mistaken. I would suggest you search this and other sites for string length routines and deploy the one which suits you best.

Comment: The `~s` modifier is intended to return short (8.3) paths/names...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set "vnum=0.1.2"
set "vtype=unknown"
if defined vnum (
 if "%vnum:~4%" neq "" if "%vnum:~5%" equ "" set "vtype=dev"
 if "%vnum:~2%" neq "" if "%vnum:~3%" equ "" set "vtype=stable"
)

@echo "v%vnum%(%vtype%)"
@echo.
```

The syntax `%var:~m,n%` means "the substring of `var` starting at index `m` for a length of `n`" where `m` starts at 0 for the first character. `n` need not be specified (when it means "for the rest of the string") `m` or `n` may be negative  where they mean "from the end of the string".

So - if the 5+ character exists, but the 6+ does not, then the length is 5, so `dev`; similar argument for `3`. Start with `fail` then override if pass.

Your code failed for two reasons - first, the `~sz` idea that has already been mentioned and second, thre **must** be a space before the `(` in an `if` otherwise the `(` is assumed to be part of the second string to be compared. Batch **always** compares strings - numerics are stored as strings and mathematical functions are performed by converting from strings to integers for calculations then back to strings for storage/display.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
set "var=1234567890"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%a in (0,1,8191) do if "!var:~%%a,1!" neq "" set length=%%a
set /a length+=1
REM add one, because counting starts with `0`
echo %length%
```

(`8191` is the max. possible length of a string in `cmd`)
Check for the first non-empty position.

If you expect your strings to be usually very long, better check "from back to front":

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "var=1234567890"
for /l %%a in (8191,-1,1) do if "!var:~%%a,1!" equ "" set length=%%a
echo %length%
```

(Note: this is not about performance, but about the principle)